# php using index for url routing

Tags: php, frameworks

today i started to work on a project that was not completed by previous developer. Since he/she did not use any framework but hardcode php, first i wanted to understand how he got his "framework" set up. So i got across his index as some kind of gateway. here is an example of this code:

```
<?php session_start(); 

    ob_start();

    require_once 'config.php'; //config file
    require_once 'global_functions.php'; //some functions we use in project
    require_once 'dil/'.$lang.'/main.php'; //language file
        switch($redirect){

        case "test" :
            require_once 'test.php';
        break;  

        case "login" :
            require_once 'login_page.php';
        break;
        //like 50 cases here
        default://i added this there was no default page before, tell if i did wrong.
            if (!isset($_SESSION['LoginName']))
            {   
                $yonlendir = 'login';
                require_once 'login_page.php';
                break;
            }else{
                $yonlendir = 'main';
                require_once 'main.php';
                break;
            }
        break;
    }

    ob_end_flush();

?>
```

What i want to learn is that, is this valid and reliable way to handle url routing? And if it is, is there any documentations that mentions this, i can check?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
global_functions.php example codes, there is more than 50 functions but no classes as well... Seems like he got overwhelmed by the project since that is not OOP at all..

```
<?php

function addDayswithdate($date,$days){

    $date = strtotime("+".$days." days", strtotime($date));
    return  date("d.m.Y", $date);

    }



function check_get_req($value){

    return $value; 
    $reparray_var1 = array("%20","%21","%22","%23","%24","%25","%26","%27","%28","%29","%3B","%FC","%E9","%2F","%3F","%E1","'", " ");
    $reparray_sil1 = array(" ","!","\"","#","$","%","&","&#34;","(",")",";","Ü","é","-","?","á","&#34;", "");
    return str_replace($reparray_var1,$reparray_sil1,$value);
}
//some calculations and array functions goes on and on....
    ?>
```

Comment: You will have to show us the included php files, most likely the global functions one

Comment: i can edit in a second, hold on

Comment: Use Slim. Dont reinvent the wheel.

Comment: BTW global functions smell. You dont need them. Use OOP

Comment: Are you looking only for route mechanism or light framework ?

Comment: Like i said this is not my project. The previous developer quit(i guess he could not handle what it was asked) and i got to work where he left.

Comment: @venkatraman both works but won't solve my problem since i'm trying to understand what was going on in this project. Anyway i'm open for suggestion

Comment: what is `$redirect`? find it and post the code.

Comment: @smoqadam you get it from url. Like this localhost/index.php?redirect=main and redirect is this $redirect= check_get_req(trim($_GET['redirect'])) ;

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you can easily move your code to `Yii2` Framework. it works nicely for your case.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2

> minimum requirement by Yii is that your Web server supports PHP 5.4.

or Use `pagekit` is trending very well.

https://pagekit.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go on with this old code, you should prepare yourself for some refactoring. Like for example, if the $request value matches the filename, the switch statement you can easily replace with something like:

```
$file_to_include = $redirect.'.php';
if(!empty($redirect)) {
   include_once ($file_to_include);
} else {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['LoginName'])) {   
        $yonlendir = 'login';
                include_once 'login_page.php';
    }else{
        $yonlendir = 'main';
        include_once 'main.php';
    }
}
```

But in this case I would also suggest some checking if the files are available `file_exists($file_to_include)` and au con­t­raire go to the default page. The story can get ugly.
It's really a hard job to reuse or refactor such functional programming spaghetti-code. Try to migrate the whole stuff to some lightweight framework (It will cost you less nervs :) )